# How to add a javaScript library in Cordova visual studio?

Tags: javascript, cordova, visual-studio-2015, twitter-oauth, visual-studio-cordova

I have been trying to use the twitter api on cordova visual studio, for this I need to use OAuth for authentication for requests. I would like to use the https://github.com/BoyCook/TwitterJSClient.git twitter client. The built in nuGet package manager does not have this library. How can I install this JS library in my cordova msvs?

I tried using npm on the command line to intall this library but I get this error. What does it mean?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like this javascript library is published on NPM: https://www.npmjs.com/package/twitter-node-client. To add this to your project, open the package.json file and put this in your dependencies section:

`"twitter-js-client": "0.0.5"`

You'll then see the "Dependencies" node in solution explorer say "(Restoring...)", and soon you'll see a node_modules folder appear in solution explorer. If you don't, turn on "show all files". This is what you should see:

[image]

You can then copy the library files into your www folder and consume them in your app (hopefully they work with Cordova!).

Comment: I did try to add that to my dependencies however I got npm  - not installed with a small warning sign on the folder.  Might you know the fault? Thank you!

Comment: Not sure. It seemed to work for me. Do you see all of the files in node_modules? If so I wouldn't worry (it is a warning).

Comment: I cant find the library files. It did install under npm but I cannot find the library files. Btw, can node applications work on cordova?

Comment: Did you turn on "Show all files" in the solution explorer?

Comment: Thank you for that! However as you can see we have the lib folder and the index.js inside the node_module. Am I only suppose to transfer the lib contents to my www? Specifically .js files into www/scripts, is this correct?

Comment: Yes, you have to copy the files into www.