# How to add javascript library or packages in cordova?

Tags: javascript, cordova, package-managers

I am developing Android app using cordova, and I want to add some javascript library in my project. For example, if I want to add `async.js`, `Openlayers` and some other library in my cordova app and I don't want to add them manually, how should I resolve this?

Comment: There is a folder inside `www` folder named `js` put your script there and then reference them inside your index.html file.

Comment: This is how you add scripts "manually", I'm looking for some package manager solutions.

Comment: you can use anything that builds a spa, requirejs, webpack, bower, etc.

Comment: @dandavis, the solution to this problem is quite flexible, I'll provide a bower one.

Comment: use this npm package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm

Comment: See Michael Braude's answer (the accepted answer) in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817578/how-to-add-a-javascript-library-in-cordova-visual-studio) question.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35817578/how-to-add-a-javascript-library-in-cordova-visual-studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We're doing a Cordova app where I work right now.

We primarily use `npm` to download any dependencies (like [`lodash`](https://lodash.com/docs), for example, or any other dependencies available via `npm`). Then we use [webpack](https://webpack.github.io/) to bundle all of the dependencies, and then reference the bundle in `www/index.html`:

```
<script src="bundle.js"></script>
```

Comment: That should work, but I've found a solution of using npm+bower+grunt to manage the dependencies.

Comment: Although I resolved this with my familiar knowledge, I think webpack is simpler to use and learn.

Comment: if I want to export my development as a cordova plugin, will the webpack bundle be included as well?

Comment: I actually successfully built the `bundle.js` and it had everything I need. But when I wanted to use functions inside `bundle.js` in `app.js`, it failed and gave me "bundle is not defined" error.

Comment: Check this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm

Answer (score 1):

I'm using `npm+bower+grunt`to manage the depencies, and it works.

In `npm`, you will define the packages you need including the cordova plugins in `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "i18n",
  "version": "1.3.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "cordova": "~5.3.3",
    "grunt": "~0.4.5",
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": ">=0.10.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "test": "grunt test"
  },
  "cordovaPlatforms": [
    "ios",
    "android"
  ],
  "cordovaPlugins": [
    "org.apache.cordova.device",
    "cordova-plugin-compat",
    "cordova-plugin-console",
    "cordova-plugin-geolocation"
  ]
}
```

Then you will manage your dependencies in `bower.json`, for example:

```
{
  "name": "i18n",
  "version": "1.3.0",
  "dependencies": {
    "ngCordova": "~0.1.18",
    "ng-cordova-oauth": "~0.1.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "ngCordova": "~0.1.15-alpha"
  }
}
```

How you build the project is through `grunt build`, and you want to build the `src` into `www` or `asset/www`. And you can `cordova run <platform>` or `grunt serve` to run the app.

Comment: Check this package https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm

Answer (score 0):

#### TLDR and simple

Use the npm package: [`cordova-import-npm`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-import-npm)

#### Long question and DIY

Because I wanted to avoid bundlers such as webpack or grunt, I used an Apache Cordova Hook

Just add this to your `config.xml`

```xml
<hook src="hooks/importNpmPackages.js" type="before_prepare"/>
```

And create this file `hooks/importNpmPackages.js`

```js
const fse = require('fs-extra')
const path = require('path')

const twoSpaces = '  ' // for log indentation
var projectRoot

module.exports = function (context) {
  console.log(`${context.hook} : ${path.relative(context.opts.projectRoot, context.scriptLocation)}`)

  projectRoot = context.opts.projectRoot
  console.log(twoSpaces + 'Project root directory: ' + projectRoot)
  copyFile('jquery', path.join('dist', 'jquery.min.js'), path.join('www', 'js', 'res', 'jquery.min.js'))

  copyFile('bootstrap', path.join('dist', 'js', 'bootstrap.min.js'), path.join('www', 'js', 'res', 'bootstrap.min.js'))
  copyFile('bootstrap', path.join('dist', 'css', 'bootstrap.min.css'), path.join('www', 'css', 'res', 'bootstrap.min.css'))
}

function copyFile (npmPackage, // oficial name of the npm package from which the file is to be copied from
  fileRelativePath, // file path with respect to the main directory of the npm package (node_modules/<package>/)
  destFilePath) { // file's path to where it is copied, relative to the project bin/ directory
  // trick to get the npm module main directory
  // https://stackoverflow.com/a/49455609/1243247
  const packageDirFullpath = path.dirname(require.resolve(path.join(npmPackage, 'package.json')))
  const fileOriginFullPath = path.join(packageDirFullpath, fileRelativePath)
  const fileDestFullPath = path.join(projectRoot, destFilePath)

  fse.copySync(fileOriginFullPath, fileDestFullPath)

  const consoleMsg = npmPackage + ': ' +
    path.relative(projectRoot, fileOriginFullPath) + ' -> ' +
    path.relative(projectRoot, fileDestFullPath)

  console.log(twoSpaces + consoleMsg)
}
```

It simply copies the desired dependencies files to the www folder where you decide. In this exemple I copy jquery and bootstrap.